# File History forgets itself and prompts for wrong destination

Tags: backup, file-history

I purchased a new NAS device and I've created a FileHistory share on it for my File History backups.

All works well until the device goes offline for some reason: I have to restart it, a power bump, etc. After that, Windows forgets where my File History drive (destination) is and prompts me to reselect. A short list of previous backups is displayed and I'm required to pick an item from the list before the OK button becomes enabled.

The trouble is that these previous backups are always all from a different profile on the same computer. You see, I keep two profiles for myself: Work and Home. When File History is working properly it keeps everything separate under its appropriate folder on the share (`\\Device\Share\Work` ~ `\\Device\Share\Home`). All is right with the world; the birds are singing, the sun is shining and water is babbling in the brook.

Enter a device offline event.

Everything gets mixed up somehow and File History running under Work prompts me to reselect a destination, thinking (incorrectly) that its most recent backups are the ones that it finds under `\\Device\Share\Home`. When I select one of those, backup proceeds normally except that my Work files are then stored under the share's Home folder.

Myself being one who prefers to not have my peas and carrots touch on my plate, I'd like to avoid this scenario. I don't mind having to reselect as that action is trivial—although I do believe that FH should be smart enough to survive one of these events—but it does trouble me that my files are going to the wrong place. My only option (so far) has been to rename the old folders and start completely new File History backups for each profile.

How can I prevent this happening and, moreover, fix it after it does happen?

In summary:

1. Why doesn't FH survive a device offline event, and instead prompts
   for a new destination upon reconnection?
2. Why is FH running under Work incorrectly identifying backups under `\\Device\Share\Home` as its most recent sessions?
3. How can we prevent #2 from happening?
4. How can we fix #2 if/when it does happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find the answer to #4 above.

If/when you find yourself in this situation, perform these steps:

- Note your current profile name (Work, Home, John, Mary, etc.)
- Using File Explorer, navigate to **{Profile}\{Computer}\Configuration** on your File History drive/share
- Note the **Date Modified** value of the two ***.edb** files in that folder
- Compare these timestamps to the timestamps presented in the File History dialog
- In the File History dialog, select the backup that corresponds to one of the timestamps
- Click **OK**
- When prompted to confirm that you're not using the most recent backup, click **Yes**

This will resume File History under your current profile and the backups will be stored in the correct folder on your File History drive/share.

As to why the problem occurs in the first place, it's still a mystery.

Comment: When you say, "navigate to", are you referring to using the FH UI?, or Explorer?  Once you've selected the backup, (which one should I use?), then how do you tell FH to use it?

Comment: @DaaBoss: I've edited to add a couple of clarifications that might help. Let me know if it's still not clear.